# jquery get the parent of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, parent

I'm trying to hide a layer but can't seem to figure out how to get this working here's what i'm trying

```
if ($('#dgAvailable_ctl02_lblpricefrom > strong').text() == '£'){
    $('#dgAvailable_ctl02_lblpricefrom').parent().parent().hide()
}
```

And my code is

```
<div class="resultsitem" style="background-color: rgb(238, 229, 208);">

<div class="petspeoplecontainer">
<h5><span class="lblpricefrom" id="dgAvailable_ctl02_lblpricefrom"><br>From <strong>£</strong></span></h5></div>

</div>
```

So i'm trying to hide the layer `resultsitem` if the text of `dgAvailable_ctl02_lblpricefrom` = `£`

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like this:

```
if ($('#dgAvailable_ctl02_lblpricefrom > strong').text() == '£'){
    $('#dgAvailable_ctl02_lblpricefrom').closest('.resultsitem').hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parent of pricefrom is the h5 and then the container div.  What I think you might want is:

```
$('#dgAvailable_ctl02_lblpricefrom').parents("div.resultsItem").hide();
```

I'd also note that hard coding your asp.net control IDs like this may cause you problems down the line...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work here. http://jsfiddle.net/SsVrE/